# unable to close Jquery Dialog from inside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to close a Jquery Dialog from inside, but it doesn't work.

I have used all closing variants I could find but none work.

The dialog is called from a main page. When I press the submit button on the dialog a form is posted (this all works fine) but the close event does not fire.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#eventForm").submit(function(e) {

                alert("HELLO");
                //Cancel the link behavior
                e.preventDefault();

                if(document.eventForm.title.value == ""){
                    alert("<?php echo $lang['titlemissing'] ?>");
                    return;
                }


                if(document.eventForm.activity.value == ""){
                    alert("<?php echo $lang['activitymissing'] ?>");
                    return;
                }

                var url = "calendar/eventsubmit.php<?php echo $qstr ?>";


                 $.post(
                 "calendar/eventsubmit.php<?php echo $qstr ?>",
                 $(this).serialize(),
                    function(data){
                          alert("closing");  
                           }   
                  );   
                  // NONE of the work ???
                  $(this).closest('.ui-dialog').dialog('close'); 
                  $(this).closest('#dialog').dialog('close');
                  $(this).closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close');
                  $(this).dialog('destroy');
                  $(this).dialog('close');
                  $(this).closest('#dialog').close();
          $('#dialog').dialog('close');


            });
        });
```

The DOM does contain the ui-dialog and ui-dialog-content elements.

```
<div tabindex="-1" class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable ui-resizable" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-dialog" style="z-index: 1004; >
<div class="window ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" id="dialog" style="min-height: 0px; width: auto; display: block; height: 105px;">
```

**EDIT**

After a lot of tweaking it works now. Point is, I did not include the jquery-custom css. Instead I used my own css with also a ui-dialog element in it. I am not sure though if that is the solution to this problem. But it is my best guess.

This is the final code.

```
<script>
        // submit the event (add, update)
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#eventForm").submit(function(e) {

                //Cancel the link behavior
                e.preventDefault();

                if(document.eventForm.title.value == ""){
                    alert("<?php echo $lang['titlemissing'] ?>");
                    return;
                }

                if(document.eventForm.activity != undefined){

                    if(document.eventForm.activity.value == ""){
                    alert("<?php echo $lang['activitymissing'] ?>");
                    return;
                    }
                }       

                 $.post(
                 "calendar/eventsubmit.php<?php echo $qstr ?>",
                 $(this).serialize()); 

                 //close current dialog
                $(this).closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close');
                // show OK

                $("#dialog").load("calendar/actionsuccess.php", function(){
                        $('#dialog').dialog({
                        title : 'Success',
                        autoResize : true,
                        width: 'auto',
                        close: function(event, ui) { window.location.href = "calendar.php"; }
                        })
                    });

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Thanks,
Coen

Comment: are you putting the dialog close inside the `$.post` completion callback?

Comment: yes but this does not work either. I tried hide() and this works.

Answer (score 1):

If you are putting the dialog close code inside the completion callback:

```
function(data) {
    alert("closing");
    // .dialog('close') here  
}
```

then `this` no longer refers to the form, it'll be whatever context jQuery has supplied.

You should create a copy of the original `this` and then refer to that:

```
var form = this;
...

$.post(..., function(data) {
    ...
    $(form).closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close');
});
```

Comment: hi Alnitak, note that the close calls are outside of the $.post call. But I will give it a try to add the close inside the post call.

Comment: maybe it has something to do with the fact that the dialog is an external php page ? I load the external page into dialog with the load() method.

Comment: @CoenDamen does the form actually even get submitted?  i.e. do you see the alert?

Comment: Hi, yes the form is submitted, everything works fine, except the close()

Comment: @CoenDamen that just shouldn't happen.  You must have something else preventing it (`onBeforeDialogClose` ?)

Comment: @CoenDamen so try to create a jsfiddle that minimally replicates your problem.  It'll either help us solve it, or help you find the problem for yourself.

Comment: @CoenDamen did you have that `ui-dialog` class on your own elements?  That could prevent `.dialog('close')` from finding the wrapper div that contains your contents.

Answer (score 1):

Try this 
It will trigger the close button event which is in the dialog header.

This is working fine for me to close the dialog

```
function btnClose() {
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").trigger('click');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

> $('.ui-dialog').hide();

Comment: Hi Kabilan, this works! still very strange that close does not work (??)